# TortoiseHG - how to display a list of files with source control info

Tags: version-control, tortoisehg

I'm learning to use the TortoiseHG/Workbench. I'm using local repositories with some web server for browsing which comes with the Workbench.

Is there a way to browse the source code while having a source control info displayed next to the list of files in the folder? I'm looking for a code browsing view similar to what "github" or sourceforge provides.

Changing the setting for the web server to github style does not seem to affect the way the project files are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several alternative Mercurial web servers, with more features than the built-in one that you are using:

- [RhodeCode](http://rhodecode.org/)

  - [demo site](http://demo.rhodecode.org/)
  - [file list with source control info](http://demo.rhodecode.org/rhodecode-dev/files/tip/) (from demo site)
- [SCM Manager](http://www.scm-manager.org/)

  - [screenshots](http://www.scm-manager.org/screenshots/)
  - [screenshot of file list with source control info](http://www.scm-manager.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/2011/06/screen-files.jpg)

Both are some kind of "GitHub / Bitbucket for your own server".
Is this what you want?

Comment: Rhode seems to be closer to what I am looking for but I'll play with the SCM as well. Many thanks. Alex